# Коготь и ноготь

Tags: лингвистика

Слова отличаются одной буквой. Но первое относится к животным, а второе — к человеку. Почему так? В чем разница между этими словами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ноготь- от праслав.«noga» - «копыто - нога животного» и «коготь - нога птицы». Потом значение слова «нога»переосмыслилось, вытеснило слово со значением нижней конечности человека «korkъ»(от него осталось окорок) и и.е.  «pes» - пех (от него осталось пехота). Переосмыслилось и слово  ноготь –роговой покров на конце пальца человека, а для рогового покрытия на концах пальцев животных и птиц было другое название –кокоть – кокъть, кот. под влиянием слова «ноготь» превратилось в коготь.
Таким образом, коготь- от *kоgъtъ(косточка пальца, крючок), в диалектах осталось кока – удар костью согнутого пальца и  кокоток- сустав пальца.Первоначально это относилось и к человеку, и к животному и птице, потом осталось за птицами, потому что их когти были похожи на крючок. Некоторые учёные говорят, что это «ноготь» изменилось фонетически, Н уподобился последующему Г. В русских диалектах путают слова ноготь-коготь-кокоть-нокоть.
В любом случае понятия ноготь(от "нога") и коготь("крючок") когда-то относились и к человеку,и к животному и птице, потому они идентичны по значению.

Answer (score 2):

Из этимологий этих двух слов (см. ниже) видно, что  слова имеют разное происхождение, хотя первоначальное греч. ὄνυξ, ὄνυχος означало и то, и другое, но при переходе в другие стало означать только человеческий ноготь. Эти два слова просто схожи по звучанию, не более.

Ноготь происходит от праслав. формы *nogъtь, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., ст.-слав. ногъть (ὄνυξ; Супр.), русск. ноготь, укр. но́готь, белор. ногаць, болг. но́кът, сербохорв. но̏кат (род. п. но̏кта), словенск. nȏhet (род. п. nȏhta), др.-чешск. nohet (род. п. nehte), чешск. nehet, словацк. neht — то же, польск. nogieć, nokieć, в.-луж. nohć, н.-луж. nokś. Праслав.* nogъtь преобразовано из основы на согласный *nogъt- по аналогии основ на -i. Следы согласной парадигмы обнаруживает ст.-слав., др.-русск., др.-чешск., др.-польск. Ср. также ногтое́д;* nogъt- — уменьш. образование от нога́. Родственно лит. nagùtis «ноготь, коготь» (t-основа), вост.-лит. nãgutė «скунец; ноготь», др.-прусск. nagutis «ноготь (на пальцах руки)», далее др.-в.-нем. nаgаl «ноготь», готск. ganagljan «пригвождать», лат. unguis, греч. ὄνυξ, ὄνυχος «ноготь, коготь».

Коготь происходит от праформы *kоgъtъ. Ср.: укр. коготь, кiгтя́, белор. ко́каць, в.-луж. kосht «тёрн, шип». Родственно др.-в.-нем. hachit, hechit «щука», англос. hасоd, нов.-в.-нем. Hecht «щука», далее др.-в.-нем. hako^ «крюк»; с другой ступенью чередования: англос. hóс «крюк».

Использован словарь Фасмера.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, вопрос связан не с этимологией, а с пониманием.
Ноготь - плоский, коготь - острый, игловидный или крючкообразный. Ноготь царапает, коготь колет и/или бьет (домашние кошки - исключения, они царапаются "в порядке игры", боевое применение их когтей - бить). Третий вариант - копыто, это ноготь, разросшийся до "трехмерного" состояния. 
Животные тут ни при чем. У слонов, бегемотов и обезьян - ногти.

Человек - двуногое без перьев с плоскими ногтями (Платон).

Answer (score 1):

Если склоняться к существуюшей версии, что когда-то у людей существовал праязык, то этимология слов "нога" и "коготь" проста: ясно, что слово "ноготь" - прозводное слова "нога". Из чего следует, что слово "коготь" должно быть прозводным слова "ког" или "кога". В древности словом "ког" люди называли конечности как человека так и животных. Со временем слово "ког" ("кога") трансформировавшись в слово "нога", вышло из обихода, но его производное слово коготь в русском языке осталось. Сказанное подтверждаеться тем, что в чеченском языке сушествует слово "ког" ("kog" ), которое переводиться как нога, но и означает конечности животных. В доказательство к тому что это не всего лишь простое совпадение, приведу другие языковые анологии для частей тела в русском и чеченском языках как например: "шея", "ворот" - "vorta" (чеч. яз.), "колено", "голень" - "gola" (чеч. яз.), "палец" - "pelg" (чеч. яз.), "голова" - "корта" (чеч. яз.). Что интересно чеченское слово "кюг"("kug") переводиться как "рука". Я не лингвист, но думаю, что при сравнении специалисты найдут родство в этих словах. Видимо в древности у чеченцев (нахов)  существовало единое слово для обозначения конечностей "ког"("kog"). Со временем для различия конечостей человека (т.е. рука и нога), слово "ког"("kog") трансформировалось в слово "кюг" ("kug") для обозначения верхних конечностей т.е. руки.

Comment: >Если склоняться к существуюшей версии, что когда-то у людей существовал праязык   
  
С этого места поподробнее. Какой-такой праязык?

Comment: Почитайте в "Википедии" или на других сайтах статии: о праязыке (прамировой язык), о  Мо́ррисе Сво́деше (англ. Morris Swadesh),  Старостине С. А.  и др. лингвистов - компаристов.
Для меня лично это не главное, что сушествовал ли когда-то праязык или нет. Главное - я убежден, что многие языке относящиеся к разным языковым групам и семьям (что удиветельно) в древности имели один язик.
Каждый, кто сядет и внимательно сравнит слова своего родного языка со словами яызков других народов по "спискам Сводеша" приходит к "личным языковым открытиям".

Answer (score 0):

коготь в 2 раза больше и принадлежит животному а нокоть в 2 раза меньше и принадлежит человеку

Answer (score 0):

russkieslogi.ru/kogot-nogot.html‎
Этимолог на отдыхе
25.08.2013

Слова: коготь, ноготь

Очень интересный случай. Пара русских слов, которую сформировали авторы словаря. Читаем.

Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка.  КОГОТЬ. Искон. Суф. производное (суф. -ът- > -от-) от той же основы, что диал. кокша «крюк», кокши «сустав птичьего крыла», др.-в.-нем. hakô «крюк» и т. д. Кокоть (ср. диал. кокоток «сустав») > коготь, вероятно, под влиянием ноготь.

НОГОТЬ. Общеслав. Суф. уменьшит.-ласкат. производное от нога. Конец цитаты.

Форму слова «коготь» словарь объяснить не может. Так и сяк сопоставляет со словами «кокша», «кокши», «кокоть», «hakô». Убедительно перейти к словоформе «коготь» не получается. И тогда делается пассаж:  «коготь, вероятно, под влиянием ноготь». Почему коготь стал походить на ноготь, не объясняется. Нельзя же предположение «вероятно, под влиянием» считать научным доказательством возникновения словоформы. С таким же успехом можно предположить, что слово «коготь» возникло потому, что хорошо рифмуется со словом «ноготь».

Читаем далее. Этимология слова «ноготь» ещё забавнее. Да и не этимология это вовсе. Это поэзия. Уменьшительно-ласкательное от слова «нога»! Малюсенькая ноженька. Блеск. Ноготь, это малюсенькая ноженька! То ли это громадный ноготь величиной с детскую ногу, то ли это тараканья ножка величиной с ноготок? Если бы такое заявил нормальный человек, то ему бы сказали, что у него белая горячка. Давайте разбираться.

1. коготь

Буквально: по окружности (ко) поднимается изнутри (го) прочно присоединённый к основанию (ть)

Подымающийся изнутри, по окружности и соединённый с основой. Коготь выпускается из специальной сумки на пальцах лапы хищника. Т.е. поднимается изнутри. Выпускается коготь по кривой траектории, по окружности, как сабля из ножен. По другому не получится, т.к. коготь имеет загнутую, кривую форму.  Одной стороной коготь прочно присоединён к основанию, к последней фаланге пальца животного.

1. ноготь

Буквально: не (но) поднимается изнутри (го) прочно присоединённый к основанию (ть)

Не поднимающееся и соединённое с основой — явная антитеза слову «коготь».

Как сейчас говорят: «вы поняли, в чём прикол?». Поясню. Этимологический словарь перепутал причину и следствие. Словарь считает, что словоформа «коготь» вторична по отношению к слову «ноготь». На самом деле всё с точностью до наоборот. Слово коготь имеет прозрачный исходный смысл. Оно точно описывает особенность оружия хищной лапы. Слово «ноготь» противопоставляется слову «коготь». Ноготь не поднимается, не выпускается из пальца человека. Тоже точное описание, но подразумевается знакомство с когтем. Этимолог отдыхает, лаская маленькие ножки.